# Average scores from an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I need to average scores from an array. All I can find in the book says this is how you do it. There is an error at the "+=" that states, "No operator "+=" matches these operands." Don't know what I'm doing wrong...

```
double calculateAverageScore(string score[],int numPlayers, double averageScore)
{
double total;
for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
{
    total += score[i];
}
averageScore = total / numPlayers;
    cout << "Average: " << averageScore << endl;
}
```

Comment: You have to parse the strings of `score` to doubles or floats in order to use `+=`.

Comment: You cant add `std::string` to `double`.

Answer (score 3):

`score` is an array of `std::string`s. You can't perform arithmetic operations with strings.
To do what you desire, you have to convert them to doubles before:

```
total += std::stod(score[i]);
```

Comment: Also, initialization of 'total' to 0 is required before for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Score is an array of strings, you need an array of numbers (integers probably)

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why you keep scores in an array of `std::string`. You may not use objects of type `std::string` in arithmetical operations. You need to convert an object of type std::string to some arithmetical type for example to `int`

For example

```
total += std::stoi( score[i] );
```

Also your function has undefined behaviour because it returns nothing and the third parameter of the function is unnecessary. And you forgot to initialize variable total.

I would write the function the following way

```
double calculateAverageScore( const string score[], int numPlayers )
{
   double total = 0.0;

   for ( int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++ )
   {
      total += stoi( score[i] );
   }

   return (  numPlayers == 0 ? 0.0 : total / numPlayers );
}
```

and in main it could be called as

```
cout << "Average: " << calculateAverageScore( YourArrayOfStrings, NumberOfElements ) << endl;
```

Instead of the loop you could use standard algorithm `std::accumulate` declared in header `<numeric>`. For example

```
double total = std::accumulate( score, score + numPlayers, 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add elements of an string. You have to change the type of your parameter or you can try to convert the string to an double

Comment: It may not be required. There are ways to convert strings to integers or double. Just need to check validity of stings if they are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `double` and `std::string` conversion, if you'd like more stats features about your data, I would recommed [Boost Accumulator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_accumulators_framework)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/mean.hpp>
using namespace boost::accumulators;

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> data = {1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5};

  accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::mean> > acc;

  acc = std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), acc);

  std::cout << "Mean:   " << mean(acc) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```